# Stop Bootstrap alert from auto-dismissing

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

When a Bootstrap alert is shown, I want to stay until the user explicitly dismisses it. However, all my alerts vanish within 5 seconds. How do I change this behavior?

My current alert code:

```
<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-danger" role="alert">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><b>Error:</b> Error message...</div>
```

Tried removing both `alert-dismissible` class but that didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    $('.alert').show()
  });

  $('button').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('div').hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.alert {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success">
    <button type="button" class="close">&times;</button>
    <strong>Completed!</strong> Form successfully submitted...
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the results of adding "alert" as a class. The following works for me:

```html
<div style="padding:15px;margin-bottom:20px;border:1px solid transparent;border-radius:4px" class="alert-dismissible alert-danger" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button><b>Error:</b> Error message...</div>
```